# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is unavailable in visionOS - Stripe

Tags: xcode, stripe-payments, swift-package-manager, visionos

I am currently working on updating an app for visionOS support. The app uses Stripe and is an important library.

However when adding Stripe via package manager, I get the following build errors

[image]

In the latest release it mentions support for visionOS. Is there a way a workaround which still includes Stripe in the project?

URL: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios

Version **23.21.0**

I am selection the version like so

[image]

And repeating the following steps

1. Remove Stripe
2. Close Xcode
3. Delete derived data
4. Reopen Xcode
5. Add
6. Stripe Package and set version
7. Clean and Rebuild
8. Errors
9. Reset Package Cache
10. Rebuild
11. Errors

**Update: The package seems up to date**
[image]

Also mentioned here: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/3192

Same issue but solutions not working: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/3163#issuecomment-1881831237

Comment: You Xcode could doesn't pick the latest version. Check from Xcode setting here https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/3163#issuecomment-1881831237